# How to compile with minGW

Tags: c, mingw, git-bash

I am using GitBash for a C project but I have been having compilation error which used to be working before.

When I compile, a popup like command prompt screen with nothing on will appear.

I have attached the picture.

I tried

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 _putchar.c 100-main 
 100-times_table.c -o 100-times_table
```

I expected the executable file for 100-times_table.c in the form 100-times_table.exe

The attached picture will give a better understanding of the problem :

[image]

Comment: @Lundin "or you won't get an extension" Not in my experience.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI you're probably right. Actually the fact that there are separate console windows for gcc1.exe and gas.exe means that there is something seriously wrong with the compiler/environment or whatever setup.

Comment: Are you able to compile and run a simple hello world program?

Comment: Try to use a Windows console instead of gitbash.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Hmm that's correct. I could swear it was necessary at some point, but maybe that was ancient pre 64 mingw.

Comment: I too would guess that the environment is broken. GCC 6.3.0? Probably installed in the prehistoric times. Such things tend to rot. Also, is it mingw32 or mingw64? I would recommend removing the installation, installing msys2, and installing 64-bit gcc from there.

Comment: When i uninstall minGW and install again, it will work but the moment i restart my machine then the same problem will start again.

Comment: Am most grateful for all your suggestions. @n.m.could be an AI - minGW64

Comment: @Jabberwocky - its the same problem.

Comment: You probably either have some old junk in your PATH, or do not have required folders in your PATH.

Comment: @n-m-could-be-an-ai - i will check that one too. Thanks

Comment: @JusticeAgyen  the same problem with what? Compiling a hello work program or using a Windows console or both?

Comment: @JusticeAgyen also try `gcc -v ...` instead of `gcc ...`. This should display the gcc version and some other information which might give some hints.